# Start tag em seen in table

Tags: php, html

I am coding php and seen this error while I trying to do a HTM5 validator. But the things is there is no  in my whole file. Any suggestions what is wrong here?

```
Error Line 27, Column 4: Start tag em seen in table.
<em><br />
```

Edit note : I rarely want to add this code here due to the fact that's it is long and have nothing to do with the error (like I said above, there is no  tag in the html)

```
<section>
    <table>

        <?php
            include("./settings.php");

            $conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $sql_db);

            if (!$conn) {
                echo "<p>Databse connection error</p>";
            } else {
                $eoinumber = trim($_POST["num"]);
                $lname = trim($_POST["lname"]);

                $query = "SELECT * FROM eoi WHERE EOInumber = $eoinumber AND lname = '$lname'";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                if (!$result) {
                    echo "<p>There is something wrong with the $query</p>";
                } else {
                    $temp = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    if ($temp == 0) {?>
                        <p>0 enquiry found. Please check again your EOInumber and last name</p>
                    <?php } else {
                        ?>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>EOI number</th>
                                <th>Job ID</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Date of Birth</th>
                                <th>Gender</th>
                                <th>Street</th>
                                <th>Town</th>
                                <th>State</th>
                                <th>Postcode</th>
                                <th>Mail</th>
                                <th>Telephone</th>
                                <th>Skills</th>
                                <th>Other Skills</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<tbody>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["EOInumber"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["job_num"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["fname"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["lname"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["bday"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["gender"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["street"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["town"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["state"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["postcode"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["mail"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["tele"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["skill"],"</td>";
                            echo "<td>",$row["other"],"</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</tbody>";
                            // echo "<p>Sucess</p>";
                        }
                        ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the presence or otherwise of the `<em>` tag, you are going to run into problems because you are opening the table tag and then potentially putting a `<p>` or other elements directly inside it, which is illegal (you can put `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<caption>`, `<tr>`, `<tfoot>` elements inside a `<table>`). It would be  better if you opened the table *after* checking whether the queries had run successfully or not, i.e.:

```
<section>
        <?php
            include("./settings.php");

            $conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $sql_db);

            if (!$conn) {
                echo "<p>Databse connection error</p>";
            } else {
                $eoinumber = trim($_POST["num"]);
                $lname = trim($_POST["lname"]);

                $query = "SELECT * FROM eoi WHERE EOInumber = $eoinumber AND lname = '$lname'";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                if (!$result) {
                    echo "<p>There is something wrong with the $query</p>";
                } else {
                    $temp = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    if ($temp == 0) {
                       echo "<p>0 enquiry found. Please check again your EOInumber and last name</p>";
                    } else {
                    echo "<table>";
                    ... echo the table header...
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    ... echo table results...
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                }
            } 
      ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Sr to my attitude before. That's so much related to my code. Thanks again! I'm so appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You missed a few `}`

So this should work:

```
<section>
    <table>

    <?php
        include("./settings.php");

        $conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $sql_db);

        if (!$conn) {
            echo "<p>Databse connection error</p>";
            exit;
        }

        $eoinumber = trim($_POST["num"]);
        $lname = trim($_POST["lname"]);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM eoi WHERE EOInumber = $eoinumber AND lname = '$lname'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

        if (!$result) {
            echo "<p>There is something wrong with the $query</p>";
            exit;
        } else {
            $temp = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }

        if ($temp == 0) { ?>
            <p>0 enquiry found. Please check again your EOInumber and last name</p>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>EOI number</th>
                    <th>Job ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Date of Birth</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Street</th>
                    <th>Town</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Postcode</th>
                    <th>Mail</th>
                    <th>Telephone</th>
                    <th>Skills</th>
                    <th>Other Skills</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<tbody>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>",$row["EOInumber"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["job_num"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["fname"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["lname"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["bday"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["gender"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["street"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["town"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["state"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["postcode"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["mail"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["tele"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["skill"],"</td>";
                echo "<td>",$row["other"],"</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</tbody>";
                // echo "<p>Sucess</p>";
            }

        }


                ?>
    </table>
<!--...-->
```

Comment: Oh that's not a problem. The table end there but after this there is more of php code :)

Comment: @TreeNguyen Ah okay ;) And wich line is then line 27?

Comment: That's the line of <table> :)